# How to use SystemD for running a docker command before docker is stopped in Docker v.18.09.3

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, systemd

In my use-case, I want to backup a [Docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) using [SystemD](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) before docker-daemon is stopped.

I got a working version using [Docker 17.03.2](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#17032-ce-1). The SystemD service is defined as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup some Docker volume
Requires=network-online.target docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStop=/bin/sh /var/dobackup.sh
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The content of */var/dobackup.sh* is not that important here. It includes a docker command, which uses a given Docker volume and does a *tar* on it.

It might be important, that I am running this in the [Google cloud compute engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/), in a [container optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/). In special, in [milestone 69](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes/m69) (, which includes Docker v17.03.2).

**Updating to Docker v18.09.3**

Now, I want to update to Docker v18.09.3 (in special, I am updating the running OS to [Container Optimized OS milestone 73)](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes/m73).

The service from above does not work any more. I get the following error, when my docker-command in */var/dobackup.sh* is running:

> docker: Error response from daemon: all SubConns are in
>   TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc =
>   "transport: Error while dialing dial
>   unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock: timeout": unavailable.

The problem is obviously in *[ContainerD](https://containerd.io/)* not being available any more. I tried

```
Requires=network-online.target containerd.service docker.service
```

without success.

How can I adapt my service to Docker v18.09?

Answer (score 1):

Some users have reported similar issues with containerd.server in previous Docker versions (17.12 and 18.03). The workaround applied was:

1. killall -9 dockerd
2. sudo service docker restart

In this [link](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-error-response-from-daemon-connection-error-desc-transport-dial-unix-var-run-docker-containerd-docker-containerd-sock-connect-connection-refused-unknown/43763/6) is mentioned a similar error and how users sorted it out the problem after restarting docker service.

Comment: :-/
Do you have more information? Link(s) to relevant issues for example?

Answer (score 0):

Likely this is caused by a containerd/docker integration issue [fixed](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromiumos/overlays/board-overlays/+/1626609) in [cos-73-11647-192-0](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes/m73#cos-73-11647-192-0). Could you try it on cos-73-11647-192-0?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To be honest, I think I will not find time soon for trying it out.